# R Shiny selectize.js item creation

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

`selectize.js` has an item creation option as mentioned on  http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/. I'm trying to add the same feature in an R Shiny implementation of `selectize` but unable to figure out how.

Thanks for your help!

PS: Some more details about what exactly I'm doing - I have some sort of free text vector that I let the user add to. However, I want Shiny to prompt the user with the existing free text values that have previously been added in case the user wants to repeat one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is to set `create` option to true:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  server = function(input, output, session) {
      observe({ print(input$foo) })
  },
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(
       "foo", "foo", c(), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
       options = list(create = TRUE))
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to a list of options that are allowed apart from create please?

Comment: As far as I know these are the same as the ones you use directly in [`selectize.js`](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#general).