# Get incomplete input from selectizeInput

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, selectize.js

I am using selectizeInput in order to have a list of autocompletable words as exemplified in the app below.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$word <- renderText({
        input$selInp
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectizeInput('selInp', label  ='', 
                           selected = 'like',
                           choices = c('like','eat','apples','bananas'))
        ),
        textOutput('word')
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Something I would like to be able to do is to take in outputs that do not match the `choices` as well. So if I write "orange" I would like to be able to display it in the `textOutput`. Is there a way to tell `selectizeInput` to not be so selective about the inputs it takes?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223770/r-shiny-selectize-js-item-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `create` option:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$word <- renderText({
    input$selInp
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput('selInp', label  ='', 
                     selected = 'like',
                     options = list('create' = TRUE),
                     choices = c('like','eat','apples','bananas'))
    ),
    textOutput('word')
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: hmm not exactly as I guess it forces users to add it permanently for themselves and requires a confusing mouse click (add). The exact intention is to notice the user is entering something wrong, read what they wrote and tell them "hey. I see you are writing that but that's not a real option. here's why..." Though this does fit with the confines of the original question

Comment: if you want something specific that selectize doesn't support, you could look for alternative javascript libraries that do support your desired behaviour. Once you find a JS library you want to use, making the bindings for it into shiny isn't too much work